# sitecore CMS 7.2 instance has DMS enabled but Executive Insight Dashboard does not show any diagram based on the data recorded

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2, sitecore-dms

Our sitecore CMS 7.2 instance has DMS enabled. The analytics database keeps tracking data but the Executive Insight Dashboard does not show any diagram based on the data recorded.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Regards,
lk

Comment: i am getting this message oncw i open the Executive Insight Dashboard

Executive Insight Dashboard requires Microsoft Silverlight 5 to run.
Silverlight is a small, safe, cross-platform browser plugin created and supported by Microsoft.


 Get Microsoft Silverlight   but i have latest silverlight installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you by any chance, using chrome browser?.. I read that NPAPI plugins like Silverlight  are not supported by chrome anymore ..

> NPAPI(Netscape Plug-in API) support will be completely removed from
>   Chrome. We expect this to happen before the end of 2014. – (Google
>   Chrome team)

ref #1: 
http://www.overdigital.com/2014/09/08/silverlight-stopped-will-stop-working-chrome-browser-now/

ref #2: http://techhelpkb.com/enable-silverlight-in-google-chrome-42/

The only alternative is to use alternative browsers, however, I'm still having problems getting it to  work in Firefox.. Do let me know.. if you found the solution to this problem.. asI too am trying to get the Executive Insight Dashboard to work. On Firefox now.. I just see a blank screen.. :(

Comment: I am still having the same problem :(